# regular expressions on URL

Tags: regex

I need a little assistants with my poor regex chops. I am trying to grab the 41398 from the URL. This number is a variable

```
http://www.website.com/beta/flips/index/41398_1363874140/friend/756
```

I figured out how to grab everything up to the / after index.

```
var url      = document.URL;
var myRegexp = /index(.*)/;
var match    = myRegexp.exec(url);
```

this leaves me with /41398_1363874140/friend/756....

Is there a solution with regEx to grab the number between / and _ ?

I tried

```
var url      = document.URL;
var myRegexp = \/(.*?)\_;
var match    = myRegexp.exec(url);
```

and of course the '/' is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know there will always be an underscore you can use:

```
var url      = document.URL;
var myRegexp = /\d+_/;
var match    = myRegexp.exec(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the first match? If not, then you can directly use:

```
var url      = document.URL;
var myRegexp = /index\/(.*?)_/;
var match    = myRegexp.exec(url);
```

Well, you were almost close. Underscores do not need to be escaped.

Otherwise, you could use your first match (adding those after your first 3 lines of code above):

```
var myNewRegexp = /\/(.*?)_/;
var NewMatch    = myNewRegexp.exec(match);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/\/index\/(\d+)/
```

which means the first group matches the number.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that matches just the number `(?<=index/)[0-9]*(?=_)`. You didn't say what language you are working in so that would help make this more specific